# Overloading operators for adding two doubly linked lists

Tags: c++

I need help with overloading '+' operator for adding together two doubly linked lists. I cannot compile my program due to getting "no match for operator=..." error. I have overloaded '=' operator already but struggle to print the result of the addition to std output. I have also overloaded the << operator. Been trying to figure out what is wrong for hours with no success. Any hints how to tackle this problem and/or solutions to it are very welcome. It is assignment for my OOP class.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The basic idea behind the code is to replicate set. Overloaded operators '+' should work as an union and '*' as intersection. I struggle to get the union properly printed to std output. '+=' seems to work fine. '<<' works good as well, but only when it comes to printing out single list.

---

EDIT:
Errors produced by compiler (g++, output from code::blocks, I have removed compiler notes):

```
llist3.cpp|149|error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘LList’ and ‘LList’)|
llist3.cpp|106|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘LList’ to ‘LList&’|
llist3.cpp|151|error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘LList’ and ‘LList’)|
llist3.cpp|106|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘LList’ to ‘LList&’|
llist3.cpp|152|error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka       std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘LList’)|
```

---

```
   #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class LList {
public:
    struct Node {
        int elem;
        Node* succ;
        Node* prev;
        Node() : succ(0), prev(0), elem(0) {}
    };
    LList();
    LList(LList& list);
    ~LList();

    Node* next();
    Node* begin()  { curr = head; }

    int getElem() { return curr->elem; }
    void addElem(int elem);
    LList operator+(LList& set);
    LList operator+(int elem);
    LList& operator+=(LList& set);
    LList& operator+=(int elem);
    LList& operator=(LList& list);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, LList& obj);
 private:
    Node* curr;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int size;
    void pushFront(Node* n);
    void pushInside(Node* n);
    void pushBack(Node* n);
};

LList::LList() : head(0), tail(0), size(0), curr(0) {}
LList::LList(LList& list) : size(0), curr(0), head(0), tail(0) {
    list.curr = list.head;
    while(list.curr) {
        addElem(list.getElem());
        list.next();
    }
}
LList::Node* LList::next() {
    if (curr)
        return (curr = curr->succ);
    else
        return 0;
}
void LList::addElem(int elem) {
    Node* n = new Node;
    n->elem = elem;
    if (curr) {
        if (curr == head && elem < curr->elem) {
            pushFront(n);
        }
        else if (elem > curr->elem) {
            curr = curr->succ;
            addElem(elem);
        }
        else if (elem < curr->elem && elem > (curr->prev)->elem) {
            pushInside(n);
        }
        else if (elem < curr->elem) {
            curr = curr->prev;
            addElem(elem);
        }
    } else {
        pushBack(n);
    }
}
void LList::pushFront(Node* n) {
    head = n;
    n->succ = curr;
    curr->prev = n;
    n->prev = 0;
    curr = n;
    size++;
}
void LList::pushInside(Node* n) {
    (curr->prev)->succ = n;
    n->succ = curr;
    n->prev = curr->prev;
    curr->prev = n;
    size++;
}
void LList::pushBack(Node* n) {
    if (!head) {
        head = n;
    } else {
        tail->succ = n;
        n->prev = tail;
    }
    tail = n;
    curr = n;
    size++;
}
LList::~LList() {
    for (curr = head; curr;) {
        Node* temp = curr->succ;
        delete curr;
        curr = temp;
    }
}
LList& LList::operator=(LList& list) {
    list.begin();
    if (this != &list) {
        for (curr = head; curr;) {
            Node* temp = curr->succ;
            delete curr;
            curr = temp;
        }
        while (list.curr) {
            addElem(list.getElem());
            list.next();
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, LList& list) {
    LList::Node* p = list.head;
    os << "{ ";
    while(p) {
        os << p->elem << (p->succ ? ", " : "");
        p = p->succ;
    }
    os << " }" << endl;
    return os;
}
LList LList::operator+(LList& set) {
    LList temp = *this;
    temp += set;
    return temp;
}
LList LList::operator+(int elem) {
    *this += elem;
    return *this;
}
int main() {
    LList setA;
    setA.addElem(1234);
    setA.addElem(1435);
    setA.addElem(1100);
    LList setB;
    setB.addElem(1234);
    setB.addElem(1435);
    setB.addElem(5100);
    setB = setA + 1234; // 1st error here
    LList setD;
    setD = setA + setB; //2nd
    cout << setA + setB << endl; //3rd
}
```

Comment: TL;DR! Please narrow down your code to just the parts you have problems with. The best is if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show only that. Also, there's not many people here who read Polish(?), so please have comments and output in English.

Comment: Sorry for that, first time posting here. Will update it asap.

Comment: The procedure is like that: you par down your code to one source file of 10-100 lines or so, make sure you are still getting the error you want to get help about, and then post your source file **in its entirety and without any editing**. Don't forget to include **unedited** error messages (or a few initial lines, if the list is too long). If what you have posted cannot be copied as is and compiled to get the exact same error you want help with, you are wasting everyone's time.

Comment: What addElem method does?

Comment: Adds element to list according to its value. That way the list is sorted in ascending order. Sorry if I have shorten the code too much. My minimal example is still 150 lines long.

Comment: @AndrzejSmyk - A little advice -- your `operator=` could be *much* simpler.  `{ LList temp(list); std::swap(temp.head, head); std::swap(temp.size, size); std::swap(temp.curr, curr); std::swap(temp.tail, tail); return *this; }`

Comment: "My minimal example is still 150 lines long." Go ahead and post it. It's better than having no minimal example at all.

Comment: If you have `+=` working, then that implies that `+` should also work (if you have implemented `+` in terms of `+=`).  If not, then there is a bug in `+=`, not `+`

Comment: @AndrzejSmyk Your code makes absolutely no use of `const LList&`.  That is probably your issue.  Pass your `LList` parameter by const reference.  Second, you didn't post your headers -- when you're posting a program, post everything, including what header files you've included.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - thanks for the hint about operator=. I think the main problem is with assigning addition to list object and printing it out to std output. Or maybe I'm just totally wrong on the idea how these two things should work. '+' operator in full code is indeed based on '+='.

Comment: No headers apart from <iostream> were included. I was going to split program into relevant parts when it is completed.

Comment: @AndrzejSmyk - If no other headers were included, how is `ostream` supposed to compile without error?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Really appreciate as I probably would not figure out how to resolve this on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a built in "current" pointer in your list class. This is a grave design error. You are unable to define your functions correctly because of this error.

It is a design error because with this design you cannot iterate over `const` lists, and this means, among other bad things, that you cannot do anything useful with temporary lists. So when you calculate `setA + setB`, you cannot assign it to anything,because to assign you need to iterate, so you need a non-const argument to `operator=` and to the copy constructor. But you cannot bind a temporary to a non-const reference.

Even if you bypass the public interface in the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator, and copy the list directly without using `curr`, you will have the same problem with any user function that must use the public interface. That is, `setA + setB` will not be usable as a function argument. You will need to assign it to some variable first, and then pass that variable to the function.

You also cannot take a list and pass it down to some function in the middle of an iteration, and expect to continue to iterate from the place you've left, because anything that iterates the list changes the `curr` pointer.

The best solution is to get rid of the `curr` member and make most of your arguments `const LList&`. While this is not the onky solution, there are many other drawbacks to having a current pointer built into a list class so I won't talk about them.

In order to iterate the list, you have to supply a separate object that can go back and forth over the list, and a separate variant of it that can go back and forth over a *const* list. This is called an **iterator** and you need to read up on this concept if you want to do anything in C++.

In your case iterators can be `Node*` and `const Node*`. You only need to provide member functions that return the first node in the list, which you already have. Real libraries do the same. They normally wrap the node pointer in a separate iterator class, for various reasons; but for a simple homework this is not necessary (though you can do it if you want).

Answer (score 2):

There is one glaring error in your code:

```
Node* begin()  { curr = head; }
```

This code invokes undefined behavior, since you are not returning a value.  It should be this:

```
Node* begin()  { curr = head; return curr; }
```

In addition, you should pass your `LList` by const reference in functions that do not change the `LList` parameter:

For example:

```
LList::LList(LList& list);
LList& operator=(LList& list);
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, LList& obj);
```

should be:

```
LList::LList(const LList& list);
LList& operator=(const LList& list);
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const LList& obj);
```

Please change these and the other functions to pass const references.  If you want to see why you should change this, you will see the issue immediately if you tried to do this:

```
LList list1;
LList list2;
//...
std::cout << list1 + list2;
```

The `operator <<` is looking for non-const `LList` objects, but the addition "inline" returns a temporary `LList` (which will mean that the return value will be `const`).  The code will not compile due to your overloaded `operator <<` accepting only non-const `LList`.

So you need to change your parameter in `operator <<` to a `const LList&`.

Comment: I would also suggest to implement operator+ as a friend function.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Issue resolved, adding const to parameter passed to function helped. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @besworland could you please provide more details why that would be better?

Comment: @AndrzejSmyk - Why a `friend` function for `+`?  Well, try this, and you will see a compile error:  `LList list1; LList list2 = 7 + list1;` while this compiles ok: `LList list1; LList list2 = list1 + 7;`  So you need to figure out how to implement `operator +` so that the former works, or just accept that you must specify the linked list on the left side of the `+`.